# finding $k$ if condition is given

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

My attempt:

Thoughtfully  can it be said that the min value of this function $ = -\dfrac 7k$. Am I wrong in saying this. Please help me find out.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum of $\cos^2x\sin x$ is $m=-2\sqrt{3}/9$. Then we must find integer $k$ such that:

$$-{7\over k}<m<-{7\over k+1},$$

that is:

$$
k<-{7\over m}<k+1.
$$
But $-7/m=21\sqrt3/2\approx18.19$, hence $k=18$.